# Drupal 7 - print taxonomy terms on node--type.tpl.php

Tags: drupal-7

I am using the following code in my node--type.tpl.php and it is working.

However it is printing the term # in the path instead of the term machine name. What am I missing?

```
foreach($node->field_blog_tags['und'] as $tag) {
$terms[] = l($tag['taxonomy_term']->name, 'blog/tags/' . $tag['taxonomy_term']->tid);
}
print implode(', ', $terms);
```

The path that is output is blog/tag/#. I would like it to be blog/tag/term_machine_name.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'l' should replace a link with the alias if it exists. Do you have your terms being aliased to blog/tag/term_machine_name?

Comment: @JeremyFrench the URL alias is set to blog/tags/[term:name]

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 did away with term aliases or machine names, If you set the url alias for the terms then this should work:

```
foreach($node->field_blog_tags['und'] as $tag) {
    $terms[] = l( $tag['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/'.$tag->tid );
}
print implode(', ', $terms);
```

The taxonomy/term/[tid] path should be replaced with its url alias if it exists.

Comment: Thanks @chronnus. I replaced blog/tags/ in my original code with taxonomy/term/ and it worked!!!